# Laravel 5.5 Getting 302 redirect error when redirecting user to homepage after login

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5, http-status-code-302

I have searched a lot of forums and didn't find my mistake here.
I'm not very good in laravel so I'm sure I'm doing a mistake which would be obvious to more advanced developers.
My page works like this.
When new user first comes to the website there will be no need to login and user can view the home page.
Then User registers and will be redirected to an email validation page with a link to the home page but the user isn't logged in automatically.
After user confirms her email, she can go and log in.
After login I want the user to be redirected to the home page if the user is a normal user and to the dashboard if the user is an Admin.
Here is where the problem comes.
After login I get the 302 redirection error.
Below you can see my routes and different controllers I've edited.
Hope I've been able to explain the problem.
Thanks for any help in advance.

My web.php file

```
Route::get('/', ['middleware'=>'web','uses'=>'HomeController@index']);
Route::get('/home', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'HomeController@after_login']);
Route::get('/search',['middleware'=>'web','uses'=>'HomeController@search']);
Route::get('/search-all-category',['middleware'=>'web','uses'=>'HomeController@search_all_category']);
Route::get('/register/register-search-cities',['middleware'=>'web','uses'=>'HomeController@register_search_cities']);
Route::post('/company-results',['middleware'=>'web','uses'=>'HomeController@search_companies']);
Route::get('/validate-email',function(){
    return view('validate-email');
});
Route::get('/all', ['middleware'=>'guest','uses'=>'HomeController@index']);
Auth::routes();
```

My `LoginController.php` controller, where I've overwritten the `authenticated` function from the `AuthenticatesUsers.php` :

```
//   protected $redirectTo = '/home';


protected function authenticated( Request $request, $user ) {
        if($user->isAdmin == '0'){

            return redirect()->intended('/home');
        }else if($user->isAdmin == '1'){
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard.dashhome');
        }else{

            return redirect()->intended('/home');
        }
}
```

And here is my `HomeController.php` which handles the `routes`:

```
public function index() {
    $country = Country::all();
    return view('/home',compact('country'));
}

public function after_login(){
    $country = Country::all();
    return view('/home',compact('country'));
}
```

Comment: as a note, `if($user->isAdmin == '1')` can just be `if($user->isAdmin)` and `if($user->isAdmin == '0')` `if(!$user->isAdmin)`

Comment: HTTP 302 is not an error but a http code for redirection. What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: @Ben Dubuisson the error I get says the page was redirected wrongly. In my browser devtool I see like 50 attempts to redirect to home and then it gives the error. ( Sorry if rhere are spelling mistakes I'm on mobile)

Comment: sounds like a redirect loop.

Comment: can you walk me through the steps again? Login as an admin results in the loop? Login as a non admin does what?

Comment: @Ben Debuisson this is exactly what's happening but I can't figure out where I'm doing a mistake

Comment: @Ben Debuisson if user is not an admin and tries to login the loop starts. The same happens if the user is an Admin.

Comment: What is the route for the login page? What happens if you login as non admin?

Comment: The route for login is the default laravel route./login. There is no difference between logging in as an Admin or as non Admin. Both fires the redirection loop.

Comment: have you got a route for `dashboard.dashhome` ? Have you tried rewriting with below code ?

Comment: I don't think your `authenticated` method is being called at all. From the doco https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users it's called `authenticate()` ?

Comment: I'm sorry i did a mistake.The admin user is actually redirected to the dashboard. The problem is just for the non admin users. And the loop is on '/home' route. It means my browser tries like 50 times to redirect the non admin user to the home page after a successful login but it falls in an endless loop and then i see the error

Comment: that's because `/home` sits behind auth so the user is constantly being redirected. redirect them to '/'

Comment: It is called authenticated and it's a function inside theAuthenticatesUsers.php file. I just overwrote it. And it is called because the route to dashboard works

Comment: right so it looks like because `/home` is behind middleware, non admin user is redirected to `/home`, then again and again because of the `auth` middleware. redirect them to a non `auth` route

Comment: I've tried this too but didn't work. I will try it again tomorrow and will ask again if I couldn't find a solution. But thanks for ur time. It's 02:45 am here in Germany now ;)

Comment: ok also publish code for middleware please

Comment: Will do it. Thanks a lot

Comment: any updates on this @DevMan ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
 if($user->isAdmin == '0'){

            return redirect()->intended('/home');
        }else if($user->isAdmin == '1'){
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard.dashhome');
        }else{

            return redirect()->intended('/home');
        }
```

can be simplified like so (and after your comments, redirect non admins to `/` because otherwise they'll be stuck in a loop

```
 if ($user->isAdmin){
     return redirect()->intended('dashboard.dashhome');
 } else {
     return redirect()->intended('/'); // return to a route not behind auth middleware to avoid loop
 }
```